# Three "commutative" functions

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

Is there possible to have three functions $f,g,h$ such that $$f(g(h(x))) = f(h(g(x))) = g(f(h(x))) = g(h(f(x))) = h(f(g(x))) = h(g(f(x)))$$ where the functions can be defined anywhere ?

**The requirement:** $f,g,h$ are not constants.

I think functions must not be polynomials (I can hardly believe that there exist 3 polynomials $f,g,h$ with the above property).

Comment: What about $f(x)=g(x)=h(x)=x$?

Comment: Try $f(x) = x^a, g(x) = x^b, h(x) = x^c$. Then all you can get is $f(g(h(x))) = x^{abc}$.

Comment: Another trivial one is $f=ax$, $g=bx$, and $h=cx$.

Comment: Indeed, I was thinking the solution would be something not so trivial, but your answers are good :)

Comment: To "mess things up", let $\tau$ be an invertible function, $f, g, h$ be pairwise commutative (e.g. examples above). Then $f' = \tau^{-1}\circ f\circ \tau$, $g' = \tau^{-1}\circ g\circ \tau$ and $h' = \tau^{-1}\circ h\circ \tau$ also satisfies your condition. Or let $\phi$ be a function, and let $f = \phi^{(a)} = \phi \circ \cdots \circ \phi$ ($a$ iterations), $g = \phi^{(b)}$, $h = \phi^{(c)}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $f$ arbitrarily and $g=f \circ f$ and $h=f \circ f \circ f$.

For instance, these functions commute, though this is not at all clear from their expressions:
$$
f(x)=x^2+1,
\quad
g(x)=x^4 + 2 x^2 + 2,
\quad
h(x)=x^8 + 4 x^6 + 8 x^4 + 8 x^2 + 5
$$